# How can I specify the return type of a function when it's a complex object?

Tags: c#

I have a function that does this:

```
public GroupQuestions(questions) {

   var questionsGrouped = questions
              .GroupBy(
                r => new {
                    r.Answer,
                    r.Answered,
                    r.AnswerGridCorrect,
                    r.AnswerGridResponses,
                    r.CorrectCount,
                    r.Hint,
                    r.IncorrectCount,
                    r.QuestionNumber,
                    r.QuestionUId,
                    r.Locked,
                    r.Result,
                    r.ShownCount,
                    r.Tagged,
                    r.Text,
                    r.UserTestQuestionId
                },
                (key, results) => new
                {
                    Answer = key.Answer,
                    AnswerGridCorrect = key.AnswerGridCorrect,
                    AnswerGridResponses = key.AnswerGridResponses,
                    Answered = key.Answered,
                    CorrectCount = key.CorrectCount,
                    Hint = key.Hint,
                    IncorrectCount = key.IncorrectCount,
                    QuestionNumber = key.QuestionNumber,
                    QuestionUId = key.QuestionUId,
                    Locked = key.Locked,
                    Result = key.Result,
                    ShownCount = key.ShownCount,
                    Tagged = key.Tagged,
                    Text = key.Text,
                    UserTestQuestionId = key.UserTestQuestionId,
                    AnswerGrid = results
                      .Select((r, index) => new
                      {
                          AnswerId = r.AnswerId,
                          Text = r.AnswerText,
                          Correct = key.AnswerGridCorrect == null ? null : (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(key.AnswerGridCorrect.Substring(index, 1))),
                          Response = key.AnswerGridResponses == null ? null : (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(key.AnswerGridResponses.Substring(index, 1)))
                      })
                      .ToList()
                }
}
```

Here's the way questionsGrouped is defined:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Answer, string AnswerGridCorrect, 
string AnswerGridResponses, bool Answered, int CorrectCount, string Hint, int IncorrectCount, 
int QuestionNumber, System.Guid QuestionUId, bool Locked, string Result, 
int ShownCount, bool Tagged, string Text, int UserTestQuestionId, 
System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int AnswerId, string Text, bool? Correct, bool? Response>> AnswerGrid>>
```

Can someone explain how I can define the return type for this function.

Comment: Best is not to make the type anonymous, but a `class` or `entity model`

Answer (score 3):

You will need to return an `object` or `dynamic`, but isn't a good idea, *Intellisense* will not available and probably you have to use *Reflection* to get the values.

A better approach is create a class with the properties you want, maybe it is a little complex in your case, but I think it is the best way:

```
class QuestionGroup
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string AnswerGridCorrect { get; set; }
    public string AnswerGridResponses { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And returns that type in your method:

```
public QuestionGroup GroupQuestions(questions) 
{
   return = questions
              .GroupBy(
                r => new {
                    r.Answer,
                    r.Answered,
                    r.AnswerGridCorrect,
                    r.AnswerGridResponses,
                    r.CorrectCount,
                    r.Hint,
                    r.IncorrectCount,
                    r.QuestionNumber,
                    r.QuestionUId,
                    r.Locked,
                    r.Result,
                    r.ShownCount,
                    r.Tagged,
                    r.Text,
                    r.UserTestQuestionId
                },
                (key, results) => new QuestionGroup
                {
                    Answer = key.Answer,
                    AnswerGridCorrect = key.AnswerGridCorrect,
                    AnswerGridResponses = key.AnswerGridResponses,
                    Answered = key.Answered,
                    CorrectCount = key.CorrectCount,
                    Hint = key.Hint,
                    IncorrectCount = key.IncorrectCount,
                    QuestionNumber = key.QuestionNumber,
                    QuestionUId = key.QuestionUId,
                    Locked = key.Locked,
                    Result = key.Result,
                    ShownCount = key.ShownCount,
                    Tagged = key.Tagged,
                    Text = key.Text,
                    UserTestQuestionId = key.UserTestQuestionId,
                    AnswerGrid = results
                      .Select((r, index) => new
                      {
                          AnswerId = r.AnswerId,
                          Text = r.AnswerText,
                          Correct = key.AnswerGridCorrect == null ? null : (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(key.AnswerGridCorrect.Substring(index, 1))),
                          Response = key.AnswerGridResponses == null ? null : (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(key.AnswerGridResponses.Substring(index, 1)))
                      })
                      .ToList()
                }
}
```